# How to compile and run haskell program in ubuntu linux system?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, haskell, linux-mint, haskell-platform

I am new in ubuntu platform, i don't have idea how i can compile and run haskell code in ubuntu system, haskell is in my syllabus so i have to configure my system for haskell. Please show me the way.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=nZoSZhxLGy8

Comment: @dfeuer I'm voting to close this quesiton as off-topic because https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pQJFWhn1R_w

Comment: the currently maintained version of haskell on ubuntu is fairly old - better use https://launchpad.net/~hvr/+archive/ubuntu/ghc

Comment: The fact that this was the top result from googling `run haskell in ubuntu`, and that all the other results on the same page say to use `sudo apt-get install haskell-platform`, which the answers here inform us is wrong (outdated), shows that this was an appropriate question. Downvoting this is madness. It would've been better suited to use `askUbuntu`, but a new user shouldn't be expected to know the many the various platforms.

Answer (score 5):

Follow the instructions on [the download page](https://www.haskell.org/downloads). Any other approach will get out of date at some point. Depending on your syllabus, you could be fine with your distribution's packages; you're looking for the packages `ghc` and `cabal`. However, they are usually tremendously out-of-date.

If you don't know how to install packages on Ubuntu with the command line yet, or don't have any experience with the command line, I recommend you [The Linux Command Line](http://linuxcommand.org/tlcl.php), since there is a free (CC-BY-NC-ND) version.

Answer (score -1):

Install haskell-platform using "sudo apt-get install haskell-platform" in your commandline and then open another console and start ghci.

https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Haskell/

Comment: As with the other answer, this will lead to an outdated installation. Also, learn Markdown to format your answers properly.

Answer (score -3):

```
sudo apt-get install ghc
```

and if you need to use imports like

```
import System.Environment
import Data.List
```

you need to install cabal,

```
sudo apt-get install cabal
```

after install cabal, you need to update him

```
 cabal update
```

and you can install the packages with

```
cabal install name_package
```

Comment: Depending on the Ubuntu version, that will install an ancient version of GHC and Cabal, and the `cabal install` ___will___ lead to Cabal hell. Also, you don't need `cabal install` for imports, at all, as long as the modules are in GHCs package database.

Comment: true, you don't need to install cabal for modules what are already in the ghc .  I said to install cabal because exist linux distributions you need.

Comment: thank you guys for giving time on this outdated topic.